# SPDH protocol documentation

Tags: documentation, protocols

I seem not to be able to find any documentation on SPDH protocol for POS terminals. It would be very helpful if anyone could point me to some.... Thank you

EDIT: forgot to mention that i did look at this question, but the link to the documentation does not work... [An analyzer for SPDH frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601746/an-analyzer-for-spdh-frame)

Comment: SPDH is generally not used between POS and payment terminal. It's used between payment terminals and bank/acquirers. At least in modern EMV setups.

Answer (score 5):

you can try with this link :
http://www.aciworldwide.com/en/Products-and-services/Retail-payments/Payments-processing/BASE24-eps/SPDH-document.aspx

you have to provide credentials and you will be in position to download documentation.

Hope this helped you.